# Possible to change backend_type of multiselect from varchar to text?

Tags: magento2, database, eav

We have a very large multiselect with over 1200 options.  If more than a certain number are selected (around 70, give or take the id numbers length), no more additional attribute options can be selected.  The quick answer to this would be to change the backend_type for multiselect to text from varchar.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to disable cache:

```
public_html/bin/magento cache:disable
```

Then open your mysql database on the servers console (via ssh/bash):

```
mysql
```

Then open the mysql database:

```
show databases;
use my_magento_database;
```

Find the attribute_id:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='my_code'\G
```

Where my_code is the system name for your field, which you can see in the admin attribute configuration page for that attribute or looking at a form field and seeing what its name is.

Next update it:

```
update eav_attribute set backend_type='text',is_user_defined=0 where attribute_id=138;
```

Where 138 would be replaced by your attribute_id.  We set is_user_defined=0 because for some reason that stops magento from overwriting your value.

Now you have some cleanup to do:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=138;
```

You can choose to either delete or migrate this data.  If you want to preserve your data you basically have to select from the varchar table and insert into the text table the only differences between the two tables is the field type of value (one is varchar, one is text who knew).  I deleted mine though because we didn't have any data we cared about yet:

```
delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=138;
```

And you're done, load a product page, save, then verify it worked:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id=138;
```

If that is empty or only contains the values you copied over then something wasn't changed right and double check your work.

You can now renable caching:

```
public_html/bin/magento cache:enable
```

Comment: but saving an attribute through admin panel will change the backend_type to varchar

Comment: I haven't run into that issue, unless it's something to do with a recent change to core.